# O-data Nesting till iN (where n can be any number)

Tags: odata

I have a scenario in which parent and child reside in same table and their relationship is in different table

Parent table can contain data like this

```
Parent Table
----------------------
Id   111
Name  Parent
```

and also like this

```
Parent Table
----------------------
Id   112
Name  Child
```

Relationship table contains these relationship
like this
Relat Table
112 can also be parent to someone with Id 113

Question is How do we define this type of relationship in Odata
O-data contains simple example of Order-->Products where both are different entities related by Order Id

In my case parent and child both sit in same table

```
----------------
ParentId1           ID2
111                 112
112                 113
```

So how can we achieve this nested relationship using O-data?

Answer (score 0):

OData can handle this fine, if you have a general `Person` entity you can add two navigation properties to that, one called `Parent` that goes to a single `Person` and one called `Children` that goes to a collection of `Person`s. This will result in being able to do OData queries like this:

```
http://localhost/api/People('ParentId')/Children
```

To navigate from the parent to its children and this:

```
http://localhost/api/People('ChildId')/Parent
```

To navigate from the child to its parent

Comment: Thanks for your response.Odata can handle it but till only one level. In my case level can be very deep so one Odata call   http://localhost/api/People('ParentId')/Children will only bring 1st level of kids but not entire family tree.

Comment: Using nested expands you can do a set number of navigations but if you don't know how many navigations there are, you won't be able to do it like this